# how do i get data from the website? using arduino uno and esp8266

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

i have hosted a website on the 000webhost. And i have simply written a line in paragraph tags in html file( means i have created a html file..)

so i want to know to know how i get data that data in html file on the serial moniter through esp8266.

i have written a code in the arduino ide which is....

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

const byte rxPin = 2;
const byte txPin = 3;

SoftwareSerial ESP8266 (rxPin, txPin);

unsigned long lastTimeMillis = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);   
  ESP8266.begin(9600);
  delay(2000);
}

void printResponse() {
  while (ESP8266.available()) {
    Serial.println(ESP8266.readStringUntil('\n')); 
  }
}

void loop() {

  if (millis() - lastTimeMillis > 30000) {
    lastTimeMillis = millis();

    ESP8266.println("AT+CIPMUX=1");
    delay(1000);
    printResponse();

    ESP8266.println("AT+CIPSTART=4,\"TCP\",\"www.tcpss.000webhostapp.com\",80");
    delay(1000);
    printResponse();

    String cmd = "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1";
    ESP8266.println("AT+CIPSEND=4," + String(cmd.length() + 4));
    delay(1000);

    ESP8266.println(cmd);
    delay(1000);
    ESP8266.println(""); 
  }

  if (ESP8266.available()) {
    Serial.write(ESP8266.read());
  }

}
```

and the response on the serial moniter is

```
AT+CIPMUX=1

OK

AT+CIPSTART=4,"TCP","www.tcpss.000webhostapp.com",80

4,CONNEC
AT+CIPSEND=4,28

OK
> 
Recv 28 bytes

SEND OK

+IPD,4,412:HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Thu, 27 May 2021 18:07:45 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 154
Connection: close
Server: awex
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Request-ID: 2eaf3c737a5348270ebe7873cab10088

<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>openresty</center>
</body>
</html>
4,CLOSED
```

what does it mean?

thanks in advance.......

Comment: You need to provide a *full* HTTP request, not just the "GET" line. You *must* at the very least include the `Host:` header, otherwise the web server has no clue which website you want to access.